# Android -cost of retaining views throughout lifetime of Activity

Tags: android, view, garbage-collection

I would like to know the cost of containing all my views in a class and use them throughout the lifetime of an activity...here is what i mean.  Suppose i have a class that gets loaded created once in onCreate(...) :

```
private  class ViewContainer {
    TextView tv_1, tv_2, tv_3;


    ViewContainer() {

        tv_1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_one);
        tv_2 = (TextView) 
                findViewById(R.id.tv_two);
        tv_3 = (TextView) 
                findViewById(R.id.tv_three);

//etc etc. i'll have probably 30 more assignment entries here
                    }
}
```

now whenever i want a view throughout my activity i would make a call to the instance of mViewContainer i created in onCreate(...), so like this:

```
mViewContainer().tv1.setText("hello world");
```

take in mind im NOT using a listView this is just a plain old Activity.
Now my question is am i asking for trouble this way in terms of efficiency and memory management ?